# Need to improve Performance of batch Job if possible

Tags: java, database, multithreading, performance, batch-processing

we have follwoing logic for - Data fetching from database write data into

1.FlatFile

2.ExcelFile

3.ZipFile

4.trasfer ZIP to FTP

now i have written a programm and it is working fine but i am thinking about to improve performance by MyThreading or anyother way

Can anybody suggest there ideas .

please find programm structure :

```
//method to get all data from database
Vector plans=getOnlyPlanId(); // here i will have 5000 planIds

for(i=0;i<500;i++) // loop for plans/500 -----Point number 1

{

 String FiveHundresplanId="500 plans";

//i will makes first 500 plansid and send to database to get data....

Vector PlansData=getAllPlansData(FiveHundresplanId); // here i will get data like 21000+ for first 500 plans 

//now , loop for 21000 planData 



    for(i=0;i<plansdata.size;i++)
        {


      createFlatFile();

      createExcelFile();

     createZipOfallFiles();

      TrasferZipToFTP();


        }

}
```

Here i am thinking like, where i am writing data to FlatFile, ExcelFile , ZipFile at same time can ask program to execute my (Point number1) 500 plans Query and make it ready for next 500 plans , so as soons as we transfer file to FTP we dont need to wait for execution of next 500 plans query.

Will this improve performance ??

if yes any ideas how we can do it?

Answer (score 0):

Think that all your independent operations can be executed in a different Thread, and so your performance will be improve. Check thread pool executor [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) If you need to wait for several operations, for example to build the zip file and finally transfer them, you can use a lock condition on any object or use directly a [Semaphore](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) for managing your concurrent threads.